# How to copy innerHtml in one page and show it on another page?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

actually i am trying to copy innerHtml from a form which is in text format and trying to show it up in another html page linked with same js , but it is not showing up in the other page ,while it still shows up in the same page in which form is kept , please tell me some way to do that

Kindly give me a sample code for both pages if possible

i tried giving same id to that element in the other page as well , not working

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular - I would also recommend you take the tour.  Your "question" is not good enough in its current form... it is not at all clear exactly what you mean.  "another html page linked with same js" doesn't make any sense... are you asking how two pages sharing an external JS file could transfer information between each other?